# Format SQL Output

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql, cursor

I need to make my output readable. I have succeeded in doing so, for queries that I write directly.

1. I need to do the same for queries that involve a cursor, i.e. to be specific, I need the records returned by a cursor to be formatted as well. But I am unable to do.
2. I instead explicitly print the column names, and the print the records. Still, the same. Is there any way, I could retrieve the headers as well, and then based on their length, format the received records as well?

Comment: Could you put the results of the cursor into a temp table, and then query that temp table to achieve the formatting you want?

Comment: If you have a cursor surely you know what the the column names are before you select them?

Comment: @Ben I wanted that to be implicitly printed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you need is Dynamic Parsing and `lpad-rpad` functions.

With [DBMS_SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sql.htm) package, you can parse a SQL statement dynamically. I threw the code block below at the top of my head so there might be syntax errors, but it should give you the idea.

```
declare
  ln_cur number;
  ln_colCnt number;
  l_sqlDesc DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
begin
  ln_cur := DBMS_SQL.open_cursor;
  DBMS_SQL.parse(ln_cur, 'select * from dual', DBMS_SQL.NATIVE);

  DBMS_SQL.describe_columns(ln_cur, ln_colCnt, l_sqlDesc);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(l_sqlDesc(1).col_name); --First Column Name.

  DBMS_SQL.close_cursor(ln_cur);
end;
```

You also need to check the `lpad-rpad` functions if you want to format your output. Try this and see for yourself:

```
begin
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(lpad(20, "Ford"));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(lpad(20, "Prefect"));
end;
```